# How to print many variables' names and their values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a big chunk of json code.  I assign the needed me values to more than +10 variables.  Now I want to print all variable_name = value using print how I can accomplish this task

Expected output is followed

```
variable_name_1 = car
variable_name_2 = house
variable_name_3 = dog
```

Updated my code example

```
leagues = open("../forecast/endpoints/leagues.txt", "r")
leagues_json = json.load(leagues)
data_json = leagues_json["api"["leagues"]
    for item in data_json: 
        league_id = item["league_id"]
        league_name = item["name"]
        coverage_standings = item["coverage"]["standings"]
        coverage_fixtures_events =    
        item["coverage"]["fixtures"]["events"]
        coverage_fixtures_lineups =    
        item["coverage"]["fixtures"]["lineups"]
        coverage_fixtures_statistics = 
        item["coverage"]["fixtures"]["statistics"]
   coverage_fixtures_players_statistics = item["coverage"]["fixtures"]["players_statistics"]
       coverage_players = item["coverage"]["players"]
       coverage_topScorers = item["coverage"]["topScorers"]
       coverage_predictions = item["coverage"]["predictions"]
       coverage_odds = item["coverage"]["odds"]
       print("leagueName:" league_name, 
      "coverageStandings:" coverage_standings,
     "coverage_fixtures_events:"
      coverage_fixtures_events,
      "coverage_fixtures_lineups:"
      coverage_fixtures_lineups,      
      "coverage_fixtures_statistics:"
       coverage_fixtures_statistics,
      "covage_fixtes_player_statistics:"
      covage_fixres_players_statistics,
      "coverage_players:"
       coverage_players,
      "coverage_topScorers:"
       coverage_topScorers, 
      "coverage_predictions:"
      coverage_predictions, 
      "coverage_odds:"coverage_odds)
```

Comment: Instead of defining the JSON values as separate variables, you might want to store them in a dictionary, which you could create automatically from JSON data using [Python's standard `json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). You could then print them in a regular loop.

Comment: Thank you for advise but I need selected way of storing values to variables

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry for bad formatting it's issue of stackoverflow mobile app

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the JSON data loaded as Python objects, you should be able to use regular loops to deal with at least some of this.

It looks like you're adding underscores to indicate nesting levels in the JSON object, so that's what I'll do here:

```
leagues = open("../forecast/endpoints/leagues.txt", "r")
leagues_json = json.load(leagues)
data_json = leagues_json["api"]["leagues"]

def print_nested_dict(data, *, sep='.', context=''):
    """Print a dict, prefixing all values with their keys,
    and joining nested keys with 'separator'.
    """
    for key, value in data.items():
        if context:
            key = context + sep + key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print_nested_dict(value, sep=sep, context=key)
        else:
            print(key, ': ', value, sep='')

print_nested_dict(data_json, sep='_')
```

If there is other data in `data_json` that you do *not* want to print, the easiest solution might be to add a variable listing the names you want, then add a condition to the loop so it only prints those names.

```
def print_nested_dict(data, *, separator='.', context=None, only_print_keys=None):
    ...
    for key, value in data.items():
        if only_print_keys is not None and key not in only_print_keys:
            continue # skip ignored elements
        ...
```

That should work fine unless there is a *very* large amount of data you're not printing.

---

If you really *need* to store the values in variables for some other reason, you could assign to global variables if you don't mind polluting the global namespace.

```
def print_nested_dict(...):
    ...
        else:
            name = separator.join(contet)
            print(name, ': ', value, sep='')
            globals()[name] = value
    ...
```